# simple shell in c - valgrind shows memorry leaks for sort command

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm writing a simple shell in C that should support up to 2 pipes (I know that the implement for n pipes is shorter, but for some reason this is the specific request).

When checking for memory leaks with valgrind, I have no issues unless I'm using the sort command, for e.g for "ls | sort" outputs the following message:

```
==4903== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4903==     in use at exit: 760 bytes in 17 blocks
==4903==   total heap usage: 65 allocs, 48 frees, 8,533,744 bytes allocated
==4903== 
==4903== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11ACFC: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10D72A: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 2 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11ACFC: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x1166F6: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10D860: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== 48 bytes in 12 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11ACFC: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10C122: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B723: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x483E017: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11AD69: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10F0F2: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10DA99: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== 512 bytes in 1 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 5 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11ACFC: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10D89D: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== 576 (32 direct, 544 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==4903==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4903==    by 0x11ACFC: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x1166C7: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x10D860: ??? (in /usr/bin/sort)
==4903==    by 0x48AE0B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==4903== 
==4903== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4903==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 2 blocks
==4903==    indirectly lost: 544 bytes in 2 blocks
==4903==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4903==    still reachable: 176 bytes in 13 blocks
==4903==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4903== 
==4903== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4903== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The above is the output after valgrind runs the `sort`, after valgrind runs `ls` the leak summary is:

```
==4904== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4904==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4904==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4904==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4904==    still reachable: 20,381 bytes in 9 blocks
==4904==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4904== 
==4904== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4904== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

which I can live with.

I've tried few different commands, with or without pipes - and again, the `sort` is the only one causing leaks.

When I'm exiting the program, valgrind outputs that there is no errors nor memory leaks but it's probably due to the `exit(0)` call at the end.

## My questions are

1. Could it be a valgrind issue with `sort`?
2. How can I debug this further more?

I double checked each `free` call in my program, and looked for similar problems on the web but couldn't find anything.

(The code will be updated if necessary)

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Bodo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10622916/bodo)'s answer I found that my systems (Linux Mint 20 under VMware 16) `sort` does cause, or at least presents in valgrind, a memory leak. I used the `ls | valgrind sort` suggestion in order to figure it out.

valgrind output:

```
==2966== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2966==     in use at exit: 760 bytes in 17 blocks
==2966==   total heap usage: 65 allocs, 48 frees, 8,533,744 bytes allocated
==2966== 
==2966== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2966==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 2 blocks
==2966==    indirectly lost: 544 bytes in 2 blocks
==2966==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2966==    still reachable: 176 bytes in 13 blocks
==2966==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Comment: Try to confirm this by running `sort` with `valgrind` independently from your simple shell. Maybe your system's `sort` implementation doesn't call `free` before exiting from the program as the memory will be `free`d automatically when the process ends.

Comment: Make your own fake sort program that actually doesn't even need to sort, and look what happens if you call `ls | myfakesort`

Comment: @Bodo can I do this without creating another program?

Comment: @RedYoel See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `valgrind` can report an issue in the `/usr/bin/sort` program.

Your shell probably uses `fork` to create a process (or processes) for the command(s) to be executed and then calls some `exec..` function to execute the specified program. When the `exec` function is successful, the process no longer runs code of your shell but code of the other program.

If you instruct `valgrind` to check child processes, it will continue to trace the programs executed by your shell, so it will also report possible errors in these programs. Of course these errors are not related to your shell.

To confirm this you can compare the results of similar command lines, e.g. `ls | sort` vs. `ls | cat`.

---

Another way to confirm this would be to run `sort` with `valgrind` independently from your simple shell. You could try

```
ls | valgrind sort
```

If the mixed output of `valgrind` and the program you want to check is confusing, you could use `valgrind`'s option `--log-file=<filename>` option to redirect its output to a file.

---

As mentioned in [Jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/898348/jabberwocky)'s comment, to avoid checking any unrelated programs you can create your own (fake) programs that are free from memory leaks and memory access errors. To check for errors in your shell implementation it is not necessary that your replacement for `sort` actually sorts the lines. It is only important that it does not produce any errors/warnings from `valgrind` and maybe that it behaves similar to `sort` in a way that it reads data from `stdin` and writes data to `stdout`, optionally with a delay.